# How do I use the clang 3.4 toolchain under OSX for NDK builds?

Tags: macos, c++11, android-ndk, clang

The `toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.4` only contains `setup.mk` and `config.mk`. There is no `prebuilt` directory, which I guess is why `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang` in my `Android.mk` is not doing anything (it is just reverting to `arm-linux-androideabi-4.6`).

What do I need to do in order to set up this toolchain?